# New Relic, Heroku error: ERROR : [New Relic] Error running task in worker loop, likely a server error

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, newrelic

I am using Papertrail to monitor my heroku app and it seems that I am getting this same error repeatedly:

> app/web.2:  ** [NewRelic][12/13/13 17:14:17 +0000 f00d3735-79e0-4b0a-9e0d-9315444e2641 (2)] ERROR : Error running task in worker loop, likely a server error:

I read in the ruby docs [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/o/onyx_newrelic_rpm-2.12.5/NewRelic/Agent/WorkerLoop.html#method-i-run_task) that this is probably:

> This is probably a server error which has been logged in the server along
>     # with your account name.  Check and see if the agent listener is in the
>     # stack trace and log it quietly if it is.

I am not quite sure how to debug it and would love some help. Thanks!

Please let me know if my source code would be helpful

Comment: Can we please see more of the log, this isn't enough to troubleshoot.

Comment: Best way to troubleshoot this would be to open a ticket at support.newrelic.com. That way, we'll be able to see your full environment and troubleshoot the unique aspects of this case. And, to echo the above, longer & more detailed (debug-level) logs will definitely help when you open the ticket.

Comment: same here, also getting this problem